# Custom ActionBar Issues

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-actionbar

I have removed the default action bar from my application and added a custom one from scratch by using the ToolBar. I have placed an imageView inside my action bar but i'm facing two issues:

1) The imageView is not responsive so it doesn't work well with all devices. What can i do to achieve this responsiveness?
2) I also have an OptionsMenu in my app and next to the Toggle, is my app's title. Since i want my image to be centered inside the ActionBar i don't want the title there. How can i remove it from just the ActionBar?

Thank you in advance for your help and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1**:

If your image is not responsive. You have to put different size of images to support highend devices. Put the desired image to folder drawable/drawable-hdpi/drawable-mdpi....

- /drawable-ldpi For low density screens.
- /drawable-mdpi For medium density screens.
- /drawable-hdpi For high resolution screens.
- /drawable-xhdpi For extra high resolution screens.

**Issue 2:**

To remove the toolbar title

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
toolbar.setTitle("");
```

Centering the imageview. Edit you customview to centering.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_icon"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked fine and it's an easy fix ! :D

Comment: Welcome glad to help.!

Answer (score 0):

1) don't use fixed values for ImageView provide weight to imageview in toolbar custom layout.
2) layout_gravity="center" may help you

Comment: 1) Sorry but i don't get what you mean my weight to an ImageView and 2) layout_gravity does not remove the app's title from the custom action Bar. I've tried different things but none work

Comment: find your toolbar and set it to as follow in onCreate():
toolbar = findViewById(your toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);